# Blender Game Engine Edit Object: can't use "add object" to spawn a character object

Tags: game-engine

I want to use "Edit Object, Add Object" to spawn a character object, but nothing happens. It seems to be that blender refuses to add character objects since anything else I do works fine. Is there a way to spawn my object and keep it as a character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure the object you want to add is at an hidden layer. This makes object an inactive object while running the game. The BGE will dynamically add inactive objects only (it makes a copy of the inactive original).

This restriction avoids to accidentally remove the original object (which disables the ability to add more copies later on).